# Adding to an array within an array state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, state, addition

I'm trying to add functionality for adding to a state, more specifically "list", in the following state:

```
shoeList : [ 
  {name: 'Nike', 
   list : [
    {type: 'boots', revenue: '1000000', gender: 'mens', price: '49.99', id: 3},
    {type: 'shoes', revenue: '13280100', gender: 'womens', price: '99.99', id: 2}
    ]
  }
],
```

Right now I have a component that displays a form for the user to enter new values for type revenue gender and price.

Here is the code for the component(not including the forms and text input html):

```
state = {

}

//when changes occur in text input fields
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addShoe(this.state);
```

And in the root component i have the addShoe function:

```
addShoe = (shoe) => {
shoe.list.id = Math.random();
//returns a new array so no alteration of original array
let shoeList = [...this.state.shoeList, shoe];
this.setState({
  shoeList: shoeList
})
```

}

Trying this code gives me an error saying shoe.list.id is undefined? Also I think I'm missing something to add in the component file specifically in the state. Also is there any way to directly access list like this.state.shoeList.list? I'm not sure if i have to add list to shoeList. Any help would be great thanks

Comment: 1. you're changing the type of your state: how does `shoeList` equal `shoeList.list`? 2. you are passing `state` to `addShoe`, then mutating it with `shoe.list.id =`, which also doesn't exist in `list`: list is an array, *not supposed to be* an object.

Comment: Okay I've changed the state in the component file so that only whatever the user inputs is included in the array for list. How would I go about accessing list within shoeList then?(please see edited code)

Comment: Still missing some pieces for your code. For example, in your `shoeList` array, you have objects such as named `Nike` and those objects have a `list` array again. So, do you only want to add your new objects to this only `Nike` object's list? If not, how do you decide that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, if the intention is to add an item to specifically the `Nike` `list`:

```
addShoe = (shoe) => {
    this.setState({
        // return an altered copy of the array via map
        shoeList: this.state.shoeList.map(brandItem => {
            if (brandItem.name === 'Nike') {
                return {
                    // use spread syntax for other object properties to persist
                    ...brandItem,
                    list: [
                        // use spread syntax to keep the original items in the list
                        ...brandItem.list,
                        {
                            // assuming shoe is an object without an id property
                            ...shoe, 
                            id: Math.random()
                        }
                    ]
                }
            } else {
                return brandItem;
            }
    })
}
```